# Error when printing more than one objects in one command line print () (Spyder 2.7)

Tags: python, object, command-line, printing, fonts

```
print ('Tính chỉ số BMI')
my_weight = 65
print ('Cân nặng:', my_weight, 'kg')
my_height = 1.65
print ('Chiều cao:', my_height, 'm')
bmi = my_weight/my_height**2
print ('Chỉ số BMI=', bmi)

Tính chỉ số BMI
('C\xc3\xa2n n\xe1\xba\xb7ng:', 65, 'kg')
('Chi\xe1\xbb\x81u cao:', 1.65, 'm')
('Ch\xe1\xbb\x89 s\xe1\xbb\x91 BMI=', 23.875114784205696)
```

Comment: It's printing the objects inside parentheses because you're using Python 2.

Comment: In Python 2 you can use `%s`-style string formatting: `print 'My weight: %d kg' % my_weight`

Comment: Can you copy the exception please? Also, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines on how to ask good questions suited for this community. Do some more research, this is basic Python, answer most likely already exists. To avoid confusion, add what version of Python you are using. I understand that it's Python 3 with Spyder 2.7 IDE.

Comment: In this case, you are trying to print non-string values as a string try converting those numerical variables into string.